# Using generics to create functions with return types that include a never union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the example code below in `GFn`, how would one get the generic `GenericFn` to produce `()=>void|never`?

```js
type UnionWithNever = void|never   // void
type Fn = ()=>void|never           // ()=>void|never - shows the function will return void, or throw an error.
type GenericFn<T> = ()=>T
type GFn = GenericFn<void|never>   // how would one get the GenericFn to return ()=>void|never?
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=96&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwOoOACwHIQG4QBOUAvFHkggCYA+c+RUTA9M+ZVQFCiRQBicUlAAUAShIA+CtToNiTBYqisR4qR1kFiAWigBnTEgDueqFmgAzAK5wAxsGSCjCADYuohCMCuFB0qgA0UEjEWITGUACGgkThhAB03ODQAOIQ9IQItgIAPAAqEkJiknlJvCkCQmkZWbn+mkSFLGyGRlBGSFYuVMH0UADmXmaYqelEtYLASB5ePoLF6jL0WgD8QA)

A return type on a function of `void | never` makes it explicity that the function may throw an error so `void` and `never` are mutually exclusive.  However TypeScript seems to condense them to `void` in types, however not in functions - why is that and what are the rules applied?

Comment: `() => void` means "this is a function that takes no arguments and doesn't return anything. If code tries to use a returned value from this function, it's a bug!" However, the function can throw an error.

What do you expect `never` to bring you?

Comment: @JSmart523 Type `()=>void` is not the same as type `()=>never`, nor are either of these the same as type `()=>void|never`.  Because Typescript *SOMETIMES* magically mutates `void|never` into `void` it makes it near impossible to deal with these kinds of generic types correctly - see http://shorturl.at/jmPQV

Comment: `never` is the *bottom type* in TypeScript; there are no values of type `never`, and therefore the union of any type `X` with `never` is just the original type `X`.  TypeScript's intellisense usually collapses `X | never` to `X` eagerly, although there are some situations in which it might preserve the union display if someone explicitly writes it out.  But there is no difference between the types.  As a return type, `never` doesn't explicitly mean "throws an error"; it means "if you see a return value it will be of type never, which is impossible".

Comment: See the answers to the linked questions for more information.

Comment: Do note that shorturl.at/jmPQV goes nowhere useful.

Comment: @jcalz - thanks for the links!  Sorry for the URL problem ;(  The info in the links appears contradictory: "For any set A, the union A∪∅ with the empty set is just A." and "request to better handle unreachable function returns" are not the same thing.  Hence ()=>void|never is not the exact same as ()=>void

Comment: If you have a function that returns, say, `string | never`, indicating that the function either returns `string` or it throws, then anyone using the return value of the function will always only see `string`, since, if it throws, code using the return value will be unreachable.  So the type of the return value for a function returning `string | never` is `string`.

Comment: Conversely, any function whatsoever can throw an error, even if it’s not annotated to do so.  Errors are runtime exceptions and you can’t assume any code you write won’t encounter them.  So a function that returns `string` might throw an error, in which case the return type is `string | never`.

Comment: @jcalz touche - you make a good point.  Thank you for deeping my understanding.